# Putting ':' after print does not return an error in python 3?

Tags: python, syntax-error, infinite-loop

The following loop does not return a syntax error, instead it runs forever. Why?

```
x = 1
while x <= 10:
  print :x=x+1
```

Comment: You're assigning the result of `x+1` to the variable name `print`, type-hinted with `x` as a valid type.

Answer (score 1):

If we properly format that code, we get:

```
x = 1
while x <= 10:
  print: x = x + 1
```

So this is syntactically correct Python, but `x` is used as a type annotation (like `x: int = 1`).

Type annotations don't do anything on runtime but can be used by tools like mypy to help find bugs in your code.

So this code really boils down to:

```
while True:
    print = 2
```